# metabelian groups can be represented by matrices, do we know the exact representation?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-presentation, finitely-generated, semidirect-product

We know that every finitely generated metabelian group can be represented by matrices (e.g. see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02219822 ). I am particularly interested in how finitely generated abelian-by-$\mathbb Z$ groups (equivalently,  finitely generated modules over Laurent polynomial rings) can be represented by matrices.

Is there a nice description of the set of subgroups $S$ and $T$ of the matrix groups such that

1. there is a 1 to 1 codependence between $S$ and finitely generated **abelian-by-$\mathbb Z$** groups.
2. there is a 1 to 1 codependence between $T$ and the finitely generated **metabelian** group.

I know how to represent some finitely generated abelian-by-$\mathbb Z$ groups by matrices, e.g. the wreath product $\Bbb Z\wr\Bbb Z$ and $BS(1,k)$ groups, I am a bit struggling to use it to find the set of subgroups of matrix group that corresponds to **all** finitely generated abelian-by-$\mathbb Z$ groups.

Any reference would be really appreciated. Thank you for reading.